# Divergent chart possible with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Does highcharts have an option to have a multi Y axis diverged like in the below attached screenshot?

P.S Any other option apart having two highchart types of charts, and rendering them next to each other.

[image: highcharts have an option to have a multi]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `yAxis` property as an array of objects. For example:

```
series: [{
    ...
}, {
    yAxis: 1,
    ...
}],
yAxis: [{
    height: '80%',
    ...
}, {
    offset: 0,
    top: '80%',
    height: '20%',
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2bf7tLn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply found this in reference to the same https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6rfb7jmz/